# how do i synthesize (E) 2-methyl-1-phenylpent-1-en-3-one?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, carbonyl-compounds

i need a way to synthesize the (E) 2-methyl-1-phenylpent-1-en-3-one
it's 2 days and still i can't find a solution.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! Feel free to take a [tour] of the site, and see [ask] for details about asking questions. What are your thoughts on this problem? Did you consider using benzaldehyde and pentan-3-one? What have you found about the _E/Z_ stereoselectivity?

Comment: This seems like a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a crossed aldol condensation between benzaldehyde and pentan-3-one.

In a classical approach, you would (under stirring)

1. Add your base to a dry solvent of your choice
2. Cool down (ice bath or dry ice/isopropanol)
3. Add pentan-3-one dropwise to make sure that it's all immediately converted to the corresponding enolate. You do not want self-condensation of the ketone!
4. Let it come to room temperature (and stir for a while)
5. Cool down again
6. Slowly add benzaldehyde. Freshly distilled benzaldehyde is recommended.
7. Let it come to room temperature again (and stir for a another while)

Check the progress of the reaction by TLC. You should have at least the *aldol addition* product by now. In order to facilitate elimination of water and thus complete the *aldol condensation*, it might be necessary to acidify the mixture and heat it.

There are other more modern (e.g. *Mukayama aldol reaction*, using the silyl enol ether of the ketone) and/or "greener" methods, but they are mostly a variation of the basic approach described above.